# Diferença entre ActivityContext e ApplicationContext

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Qual é a diferença entre `ActivityContext` e `ApplicationContext`?

O seguinte código, executado a partir de um `Fragment`, loga a mensagem "são diferentes":

```
 if (getActivity().getApplicationContext().equals(getContext())) {
     Log.d("Context", "São iguais");
 } else {
     Log.d("Context", "São diferentes");
 }
```

Os dois métodos comparados retornam uma instância de `Context`. Se os `Context` são diferentes, para que cada um deles serve?

Answer (score 2):

Ao utilizar `getContext()`, você está se referindo ao contexto da `Activity` corrente, sendo que ao utilizar `getApplicationContext()` você está se referindo ao contexto da aplicação como um todo.

Resumindo:

1. `getApplicationContext()` é o contexto relacionado ao ciclo de vida da aplicação
2. `getContext()` está relacionado ao ciclo de vida da `Activity`

São objetos diferentes, por isso o resultado do seu `equals` vai ser falso.